# Xamarin Forms IOS "Entry" is uneditable

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms to build my app. In the Login Page, I have the following layout

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid 
        RowSpacing="{StaticResource MediumSpacing}" 
        ColumnSpacing="{StaticResource MediumSpacing}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Two stackLayouts-->

        <!--StackLayout 1-->
        <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0">
            <!--Three stacklouts here-->
            <!--First-->
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout.Spacing>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="12" iOS="30" WinPhone="12"/>
                </StackLayout.Spacing>
                <StackLayout.Padding>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Android="32,24,32,24" iOS="16,24,16,24" WinPhone="32,24"/>
                </StackLayout.Padding>
                <imagecircle:CircleImage
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="95" HeightRequest="95"
                    BorderColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                    x:Name="CircleImageAvatar"/>

                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   StyleId="LoginPageIdentifier"
                   LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   TextColor="{DynamicResource DetailTextColor}"
                   Text="Single Sign On">

                    <Label.FontSize>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="15" iOS="15" WinPhone="15"/>
                    </Label.FontSize>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <!--Second Stack Layout-->
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout.Padding>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Android="32,0" iOS="32,0" WinPhone="32,0"/>
                </StackLayout.Padding>
                <StackLayout.Spacing>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="0" iOS="15" WinPhone="10"/>
                </StackLayout.Spacing>
                <toolkit:EntryLine
                   Text="{Binding Email}" 
                   Keyboard="Email"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Placeholder="Email Address"
                   x:Name="EntryEmail"
                   StyleId="EmailTextField"

                   BorderColor="#ECECEC">
                    <toolkit:EntryLine.HorizontalTextAlignment>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="TextAlignment" iOS="Center"/>
                    </toolkit:EntryLine.HorizontalTextAlignment>
                </toolkit:EntryLine>

                <toolkit:EntryLine 
                   Text="{Binding NamespaceUri}" 
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Placeholder="Namespace"
                   StyleId="EmailTextField"
                   Keyboard="Text"
                   BorderColor="#ECECEC">
                    <toolkit:EntryLine.HorizontalTextAlignment>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="TextAlignment" iOS="Center"/>
                    </toolkit:EntryLine.HorizontalTextAlignment>
                </toolkit:EntryLine>
            </StackLayout>
            <!--Third Stack Layout-->
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout.Padding>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Android="32,16,32,0" iOS="32,25,32,0" WinPhone="32,16,32,0"/>
                </StackLayout.Padding>
                <StackLayout.Spacing>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="0" iOS="16" WinPhone="10"/>
                </StackLayout.Spacing>
                <Button 
                Text="Sign In"
                Command="{Binding LoginCommandSso}"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                StyleId="SignInButton"
                TextColor="White"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">

                    <Button.FontAttributes>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FontAttributes" iOS="Bold"/>
                    </Button.FontAttributes>
                </Button>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <!--StackLayout 2-->
        <!--Contains activity indicator and Corresponding label-->
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <StackLayout 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Padding="16,0" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}">
                    <ActivityIndicator.Color>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" Android="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                    </ActivityIndicator.Color>
                </ActivityIndicator>
                <Label Text="{Binding Message}" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
        <!--Stack Layout 3-->

    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

When run on Android Emulator I can input text in "EntryLine" and everything seems to work fine.
However, when I am trying to run it on IOS simulator, the text becomes ineditable i.e. readonly. Basically on IOS simulator everything inside StackLayout is becoming "ReadOnly"
**I also tried using forms "Entry" instead of FormsToolKit.EntryLine, but no result.
I am facing an issue in above code itself, adding just a "Entry" in xaml and testing on IOS simulator works fine.**
*Have already asked the same question on Xamarin Forums, but haven't found any answer.*

**EDIT 1 - Added the complete stack layout.**

Using -

- Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10, Xamarin - 2.3.4.247
  FormsToolKit - 1.1.18 IOS - MacBook Air 10.3

Comment: is it possible there is somewhere a grid overlaying the entry? on android grids are input transparent - on iOS not. Try giving the entry a tap listener in some way and check if that tap is being raised (or add a button in its place and see if it can be tapped)

Comment: as @woelliJ mentioned; something could be overlapping. Please post the full layout to see what could be wrong.

Comment: @woelliJ - Yes, the stackLayout is inside a grid. 
        <Grid 
            RowSpacing="{StaticResource MediumSpacing}" 
            ColumnSpacing="{StaticResource MediumSpacing}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
I tried adding a button in its place, the button also gets disabled.

Comment: by disabled you mean that it is in a disabled state, or that it does not receive input? it's ok, that the stacklayout is in a grid - but there could be a some layout (e.g. a grid) overlapping (being in front if it - but not visible) of  the controls

Comment: @woelliJ - I have added the complete layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<AbsoluteLayout>` overlaps your content and catches all input events. You'll have to try setting its `IsVisible` Property to false (or the `InputTransparent` property to try). At least as long as the Activity Indicator is not running.

(If that is not working you might try to handle it with an effect (or a custom renderer) that sets input transparancy on iOS specifically)

(You might also consider not placing it inside the scroll view, since it would get scrolled away eventually)

Comment: The <AbsoluteLayout> was actually the culprit.
I just removed it and now I am able to edit and input in "Entry" tag.
Thanks a lot!